# Reverse Operation Add / subtract

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to write a function that receives an expression and then replaces all "-" with "+" and vice versa and gives me a new expression in racket.

```
(define-struct anode (oper args))

(define (myapply f exl)
(cond
   [(symbol? f)
         ("swap cond and recurse rest")]))

(define (myeval ex)
    (cond [(number? ex) ex]
            [else (myapply (anode-oper ex) (anode-args ex))]))
```

update...

```
(define (myapply f exl) 
   (cond [(symbol=? f ') 
             (+ (myeval (first exl) (myapply f (rest exl)))] 
         [(symbol=? f '+) 
             ( (myeval (first exl)) (myapply f (rest exl)))])) 

(define (myeval ex)
   (cond [(number? ex) ex]
         [else (myapply (anode-oper ex) (anode-args ex))]))
```

I get the right answer for the inverse of my original list...
   (make-anode '* (list 3 3 4)) --> 10   (which is correct using addition)

I can't seem to duplicate the expression though...

from -> to
(make-anode '* (list 3 3 4)) --> (make-anode '+ (3 3 4))

Comment: Have you given it a try? What are you stuck on? Do you have a purpose statement or test cases for the function you're trying to write?

Comment: (define (myapply f exl)
(cond
   [(symbol=? f '*)
         (+ (myeval (first exl) (myapply f (rest exl)))]
   [(symbol=? f '+)
         (* (myeval (first exl)) (myapply f (rest exl)))]))

I was able to do this above and get a result for my new expression.  That is inverse of the original.  :)

I can't seem to duplicate the expressio though...
(make-anode '* (list 3 3 4))  -->  (make-anode '+ (3 3 4))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like this to convert an S-expression:

```
(define (convert tree)
  (if (null? tree)
      null
      (if (cons? tree)
          (cons (convert (car tree)) (convert (cdr tree)))
          (case tree
            ((+) '-)
            ((-) '+)
            (else tree)))))
```

such as

```
> (convert '(- 3 3 4))
'(+ 3 3 4)
```

and then some Racket magic to use `eval`:

```
> (define-namespace-anchor anc)
> (define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace anc))
> (eval (convert '(- 3 3 4)) ns)
10
> (eval (convert '(+ 3 3 4)) ns)
-4
```

Answer (score 0):

A function that takes an expression and replaces `+` with `-` and `-` with `+` might be written as a simple recursive parser:

```
(define (my-parser expr)
  (for/list ([i expr])                                                                                               
  (cond                                                                                                                                   
    ((eq? i '+) '-)                                                                                                                         
    ((eq? i '-) '+)                                                                                                                         
    ((list? i) (my-parser i)) 
    (else i))))
```

The reason this works is because racket/scheme/lisp expressions are also lists. It is worth noting that this has some features that may make it case where a macro is suitable. However, since the question is about a function, this is a function and so long as a function does the job it is usually better to use  a function rather than a macro.